# Excel VBA: Interior Color

Tags: excel, vba, border

Here is my first macro so perhaps it is not the most efficient but it does pretty much all I need - it formats some text based on some requirements. There is only one issue with the output when document gets printed - there appears to be a gap in the first row, between background fill and border line and I am not able to work out why.

```
Sub Test()

'Set columns width
With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    .Range("A:A,F:F").ColumnWidth = 16.5
    .Range("C:C").ColumnWidth = 41
    .Range("B:B,D:D,E:E").ColumnWidth = 25
    .Range("G:G,H:H").ColumnWidth = 26.5
    .Range("I:I,J:J,K:K").ColumnWidth = 10
End With

'Format Content (First line only)
Dim Header As Range
Set Header = ActiveSheet.Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
With Header
    .Interior.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .RowHeight = .RowHeight * 2
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .Borders.Color = vblack
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    .Borders.Color = RGB(112, 48, 160)
    .WrapText = True
    .Rows.AutoFit
    End With

'Format Content (Below first line)
Dim Content As Range
Set Content = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1)
With Content
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .Borders.Color = vblack
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    .WrapText = True
    .Rows.AutoFit
    End With

'Format Page Setup
With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name).PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .CenterHorizontally = True
    .PrintArea = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    .TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .CenterFooter = "My Footer"
    .RightFooter = "Page " + "&P / &N"
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:3").Address
    End With

End Sub
```

Here is how it comes out when printed:
- with added borders for the first row
[with border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGovy.png)

-and no border
[no border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmcJZ.png)

Thoughts or ideas?

Comment: A picture of the problem would be useful here.

Comment: I added pictures of the issue to the description

Comment: Does it look OK on screen?  Is is possible the printer is the problem?

Comment: If you take a look at the first image (with border) there is a gap between border and background fill. In the second image (no border), where I removed the border from the code altogether in the first row only, there is gap - please note the offset between background fill from the first row and border from the the second on the left hand side.I have only printed the document to PDF but the issue can be seen in Excel under preview.

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit`?  You have some typos in there...   I see the same result though - the top-left corner does not render well when output to PDF.